# How to import cases into Oracle Argus without encountering trigger errors?

Tags: oracle

Recently, I received a new requirement to import case data into Oracle's Argus system, but I can't proceed at all (unless I disable triggers). The main table for cases is CASE_MASTER, but when I insert data into it, even though I pass in ENTERPRISE_ID, it tells me that it cannot insert NULL into the ENTERPRISE_ID field in DLP_CASE_MASTER when executing the trigger. What's going on? Is there a professional who can tell me what to do?

This is the inserting statement found in V$SQL：

```
INSERT INTO CASE_MASTER (CASE_ID, CASE_NUM, REV, WORKFLOW_SEQ_NUM, LAST_WORKFLOW_SEQ_NUM,
                                           CREATE_TIME, INIT_REPT_DATE, USER_ID, LAST_UPDATE_TIME,
                                           LAST_UPDATE_USER_ID, REQUIRES_FOLLOWUP, FOLLOWUP_DATE, OWNER_ID,
                                           STATE_ID, COUNTRY_ID, LANG_ID, PRIORITY, SITE_ID, SERIOUSNESS,
                                           RPT_TYPE_ID, LAST_STATE_ID, ASSESSMENT_NEEDED, PRIORITY_OVERRIDE, SID,
                                           SAFETY_DATE, NORMAL_TIME, MAX_TIME, REPORT_SCHEDULING,
                                           PRIORITY_ASSESSMENT, CLOSE_USER_ID, CLOSE_DATE, CLOSE_NOTES, DATE_LOCKED,
                                           UD_TEXT_1, UD_TEXT_2, UD_TEXT_3, UD_TEXT_4, UD_TEXT_5, UD_TEXT_6,
                                           UD_TEXT_7, UD_TEXT_8, UD_TEXT_9, UD_DATE_1, UD_DATE_2, UD_DATE_3,
                                           UD_DATE_4, UD_DATE_5, UD_DATE_6, UD_DATE_7, UD_DATE_8, UD_DATE_9,
                                           UD_NUMBER_1, UD_NUMBER_2, UD_NUMBER_3, UD_NUMBER_4, UD_NUMBER_5,
                                           UD_NUMBER_6, UD_NUMBER_7, UD_NUMBER_8, UD_NUMBER_9, DUE_SOON, GLOBAL_NUM,
                                           PRIORITY_DATE_ASSESSED, UD_TEXT_10, UD_TEXT_11, UD_TEXT_12, UD_DATE_10,
                                           UD_DATE_11, UD_DATE_12, UD_NUMBER_10, UD_NUMBER_11, UD_NUMBER_12,
                                           LAM_ASSESS_DONE, WORKLIST_OWNER_ID, SUSAR, LAST_UPDATE_EVENT, FORCE_SOON,
                                           INITIAL_JUSTIFICATION, DUE_SOON_J, FOLLOWUP_DATE_J, INIT_REPT_DATE_J,
                                           JUST_INIT_REPT_DATE_J, UD_TEXT_1_J, UD_TEXT_2_J, UD_TEXT_3_J,
                                           UD_TEXT_4_J, UD_TEXT_5_J, UD_TEXT_6_J, UD_TEXT_7_J, UD_TEXT_8_J,
                                           UD_TEXT_9_J, UD_TEXT_10_J, UD_TEXT_11_J, UD_TEXT_12_J,
                                           INITIAL_JUSTIFICATION_J, MEDICALLY_CONFIRM)
                  VALUES (:B96, :B95, :B94, :B93, :B92, :B91, :B90, :B89, :B88, :B87, :B86, :B85, :B84, :B83, :B82,
                          :B81, :B80, :B79, :B78, :B77, :B76, :B75, :B74, :B73, :B72, :B71, :B70, :B69, :B68, :B67,
                          :B66, :B65, :B64, :B63, :B62, :B61, :B60, :B59, :B58, :B57, :B56, :B55, :B54, :B53, :B52,
                          :B51, :B50, :B49, :B48, :B47, :B46, :B45, :B44, :B43, :B42, :B41, :B40, :B39, :B38, :B37,
                          :B36, :B35, :B34, :B33, :B32, :B31, :B30, :B29, :B28, :B27, :B26, :B25, NVL(:B24, 0),
                          :B23, :B22, :B21, :B20, :B19, :B18, :B17, :B16, :B15, :B14, :B13, :B12, :B11, :B10, :B9,
                          :B8, :B7, :B6, :B5, :B4, :B3, :B2, :B1)
```

I want to know how to insert data without causing trigger errors.

Also, its stored procedure is encrypted, and I don't even know the specific logic inside it. Additionally, when I checked V$SQL, I found that the executed statement surprisingly didn't pass the ENTERPRISE_ID field. How is this achieved?

[image]

Comment: You may need to talk to Oracle support. We can't diagnose a problem in code we (or you) can't see. However... the error stack seems to include ORA-28115, which is "policy with check option violation" (it would be helpful if you set your NLS language to English to capture the full error for posting here, as text) - suggesting there is a VPD on the table, which might explain why the ID column is eliminated. Look at the policies, or ask your DBA to do so.